# Mathematical equation editor in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, math, latex, mathjax, mathml

I'm creating a simple blog using ruby on rails 4. I want to be able to write mathematical equations with it. I'd appreciate if you could help me with any of these questions:

- Is there a gem/plugin/etc which I can use to add an editor for mathematical equations to my app? Just like Mathmatical editor in MS word I could use to create an equation and it could give me the MathML code as output?
- Let's assume that I have a form where I write the equations in Latex. Is there a gem/plugin/etc (not javascript because it will probably be a huge code and it might cause conflicts and some problems) to convert the equations from Latex/Tex to MathML before saving them to the database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Equation Editor [www.codecogs.com](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/quick-install.php)

This is designed to be physically integrated within a websites, allowing your users to create equations without leaving your website. There are two approaches to integrating the editor: either as a popup that can be activated from a button on your site, or as an object embedded directly a page. A range of plugins for popular editors are also available, e.g. CK Editor, Tiny MCE.